# Oracle SQLPlus ORA-01017 invalid credentials when specifying schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

On an Oracle11g database, this works:

```
SQL> connect USER/pass
Connected.
```

However, this doesn't:

```
SQL> connect USER/pass@db
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I have executed:

```
SQL> grant connect to USER;
Grant succeeded.
```

What am I missing?

tnsnames.ora:

```
DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = a.dom.b.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db)
    )
  )
```

**EDIT:**

```
:> sqlplus USER/pass
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Mon Mar 11 15
Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
```

The other two don't.

```
:> sqlplus USER/pass@db
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Mon Mar 11 15:04:44 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

This one produces identifier error:

```
:> sqlplus USER/pass@db//localhost:1521
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Mon Mar 11 15:10:38 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have verified tnsnames.ora entry and I am spelling service correctly.

**EDIT2:**

```
:> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on 11-MAR-2013 15:14:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=a.dom.b.com)(PORT=1521
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
Start Date                01-MAR-2013 16:15:25
Uptime                    9 days 21 hr. 59 min. 8 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   d:\oracle\product\11.1.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\TMDEV100\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=a.dom.b.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "db" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "db", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
...
...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Is your `db` valid TNS name?

Comment: Yes, I added the cleared tnsnames entry.

Comment: Does USER have the same password on both databases? You could simply have an invalid password...

Comment: Definitely same password is being entered each time.

Comment: @mdobrinin - Does sqlplus accept your connect parameters from command line?  Examples: `sqlplus user/pwd@db` and `sqlplus user/pwd@//host:1521/servicename`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, no. I have also added lsnrctl output.

Comment: And what about `sqlplus USER/pass@//localhost:1521/ser` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, no luck. Still getting ORA-01017 with that.

Comment: After connecting select from `v$instance` and `v$database` to make sure you are connected to what you think you should be.

Comment: Also you can run `tnsping db` to be sure db is resolving to the location you think.

Comment: `tnsping` works fine. As expected, without the @, it is connecting to a different service.

Comment: I didn't ask whether _you_ were entering the same password but whether the users were _set-up_ with the same password. They're not the same user and so it can be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not include the @db it will connect either via the TWO_TASk environment variable or do a local connection to the database on the machine you are connected to.  the @db will lookup the connection information via the tnsnames.ora and then connect.  I am guessing that you are connecting to two different databases.  One you have the username/password combination and the other you do not.