# How can I stop SQL*Plus from within a shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

In my shell script I have a command which gets the value from the database and stores it in a variable:

```
seq_day=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s username/password @$SQL_FILES_DIR/myScript.sql`
```

The script runs fine and I am able to display the value in `seq_day`.

The real problem comes when either the username or password is incorrect. The script never stops.

Is there any way to exit from the script?

Comment: When "The script never stops", what does it do?

Comment: I guess its waiting for input from the user.

Comment: Have you tried the that line from outside your script to check? I'd expect to see something like "`ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`", as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15346558/78845

Comment: I am getting a similar error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the following option (emphasis mine):

> LOGON Option
>
> `-L[OGON]`
>
> Specifies not to reprompt for username or password if the initial connection does not succeed. **This can be useful in operating system scripts that must either succeed or fail and you don't want to be reprompted for connection details** if the database server is not running. This option is not available with the Windows graphical user interface SQL*Plus executable.

**Source:** [The SQLPLUS Command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1005759)

Comment: The script might probably waiting for username/password from the user when it failed the first time. `-L` option seems to work fine for me. Thanks.